# Workaround for TypeError: Struct containing a (nested) mapping cannot be constructed

Tags: solidity, mapping

Following example code piece works on solidity `v0.6.*`:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT

pragma solidity >=0.7.1;

contract Campaign {
    struct Status {
        uint32 cost;
        mapping(uint256 => address) jobs; // I will set this afterwards
    }
    
    struct Provider {
            mapping(string => Status[]) jobStatus;
    }
    
    mapping(address => Provider) providers;

    function submit(string memory key) public {
         Provider storage provider = providers[msg.sender];
         provider.jobStatus[key].push(Status({cost:100}));
    }
}
```

---

When I update solidity version to `0.7.1` I am getting following error: `TypeError: Struct containing a (nested) mapping cannot be constructed.`.

When I uncomment following line `mapping(uint256 => address) jobs;` error is gone but is there any way to handle this error without uncommenting  `mapping(uint256 => address) jobs;` section?

Comment: Side note: I'd declare those state variables in the exact reversed order, to explicitly emphasize the dependency chain, and perhaps even fix the compilation error (though based on the error-message, it hardly looks related).

Comment: What do you mean by reverse order, like `Job` , `Status` , and `Provider`?

Comment: Relevant prior to your recent edit: you have 4 structures and state variables. The 1st uses the 2nd, the 2nd uses the 3rd, and the 3rd uses the 4th. Rearrange those Such that each dependency is declared before being used.

Comment: I have rearrange them but it didn't make any affect

Comment: `works on solidity v0.6.0` - by 'works', do you mean 'compiles'? Or have you actually tested it on an EVM (e.g., ganache)? I find it hard to believe that chriseth would unsupport a valid working functionality.

Comment: I have a much complex code but I put its some section, where it was compiles and works It tested on EVM, ganache and on a private ethereum network on all v0.6.* but it does not complies in v0.7.* due to having `mapping` variable inside a `struct`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that since solc 0.7 it is no longer allowed to create structs in memory that contains mappings, see [the release notes](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.7.2/070-breaking-changes.html#mappings-outside-storage).

One workaround is to use `.push()` and get a reference to the new created element and use that reference to modify it.

```
function submit(string memory key) public {
     Provider storage provider = providers[msg.sender];
     Status storage st = provider.jobStatus[key].push();
     st.cost = 100;
}
```

Comment: In gas usage will this workaround might consume more gas if the `jobStatus` struct has lets say 10 variables ?

Comment: @alper I'm don't know, you use less memory so gas usage should be lower, but you are write more code so gas will be higher.

Comment: I experience there is additional 1.000 gas usage instead of pushing all in once in to the list `[]`